# shとbashについて

Tags: bash, sh

**Q1.bashはshの上位互換ですか？**
・shでは出来るけれども、bashでは出来ないことはありますか？

---

**Q2.「#!/bin/sh」と「#!/bin/bash」について**
・下記3つあると思うのですが、それぞれ何れに該当しますか？

```
・シェルスクリプト
・bash posix モード
・bash
```

・「#!/bin/bash」は「bash」？
・「#!/bin/sh」は「シェルスクリプト」？ それとも「bash posix モード」？

---

**環境**
・CentOS

Comment: 「シェル」と「シェルスクリプト」を混同なさっているようです。

Comment: [sh; Bourne Shell](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell)と[bash; Bourne-again shell](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash)の持つsh互換モードとどちらについての質問でしょうか？

Comment: @sayuri。「sh; Bourne Shell」「bash; Bourne-again shell」「bash; Bourne-again shellの持つsh互換モード」の3つの違いについての質問です。どういう時に何が起動するのか、よく分かりません。そもそも3つあるわけではない？？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sh` というと伝統的なB-Shellのことをイメージしますが、ご質問のCentOS環境では `sh` と `bash` は同じコマンドです。`/bin/sh` は `/bin/bash` のシンボリックリンクなので `sh` といいならがらも `bash` が動きます。

> Q1.bashはshの上位互換ですか？
>   ・shでは出来るけれども、bashでは出来ないことはありますか？

こちらについてはわかりません（あしからず）。

> Q2.「#!/bin/sh」と「#!/bin/bash」について
>   ・下記3つあると思うのですが、それぞれ何れに該当しますか？
>   ・シェルスクリプト
>   ・bash posix モード
>   ・bash

`#!` で始まる行は shebang といいます。そのスクリプトファイルを実行するインタプリタを指定する書き方です。シェルスクリプトはシェルの文法で書かれたスクリプトファイル全般のことです。

CentOS環境では `/bin/sh` `/bin/bash` どちらも`bash`です。ただし、`sh` という名前で実行した場合は POSIXモードの振る舞いをします。

manpage of bash より引用

> If  bash  is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.

ただし、bash独自の「配列」は posixモードでも使えます。従って、posixモードで正常に動作する `/bin/sh` スクリプトが全ての環境の `sh` で動作するわけではありません。

> ・「#!/bin/bash」は「bash」？

shebang に /bin/bash を指定していますので、そのスクリプトはbashによって実行されます。

> ・「#!/bin/sh」は「シェルスクリプト」？ それとも「bash posix モード」？

shebang に /bin/sh を指定してますが、CentOS環境ではbashのPOSIXモードで実行されます。

なお、以前の Centos では POSIX準拠のB-Shellの代用として Almquist Shell (ash) が 用意されていましたが、Centos6以降ではパッケージングされておらず bash のみのようです。(探せばあるのかも・・・)

Comment: 今は無き(?) csh を考えると bashの位置付けが分かるかも、って気がします。 cshに機能的に抜かれた sh(ボーンshell)の機能拡張が、bashと思っているが、きちんと歴史を追っていないので、正確さは不明。ただ、bashが shの上方互換は間違いないと思います。ただし、機能を増やしたために、失った互換性もあると思うので注意が必要。

Comment: 「posixモードで正常に動作する /bin/sh スクリプトが全ての環境の sh で動作するわけではありません」について。この意味は、「bashのPOSIXモード」だったら同じ動作をするが「sh」内容はOSによって異なる可能性がある、という意味ですか？　全ての環境で同じ動作をさせるには、「bash」で作成しておいた方が無難？？

Comment: そういう意味で合ってます。bashの配列は他のshでは動きません。他にもあるかもしれませんが検証していないので他にもあるかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

> Q1.bashはshの上位互換ですか？

最初に[Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5725296)という質問を見つけたので紹介しておきます。

bashはshを基礎にして開発されています。できるだけshのように振る舞うこともできますし、shにない機能がbashにはあります。そういう意味では上位互換であると言えそうです。
一方、dashやashを始めとした様々なシェルが同じようにshを基礎にして開発されています。
それらのシェルがbashをshの上位互換とするか――shではなくbashを基礎にするかというとそうではないでしょう。

> Q2.「#!/bin/sh」と「#!/bin/bash」について

ざっくりした説明ですが、シェルスクリプトはシェルが解釈して実行できるように書かれたスクリプトです。
ファイルの先頭に書かれる`#!/bin/sh`とか`#!/bin/bash`はshebangと呼ばれていて、そのファイルに書かれたスクリプトを解釈して実行するシェルを指定しています。(前者ならshが、後者ならbashが呼ばれます。)

もし`readlink /bin/sh`の結果が`bash`だった場合に`#!/bin/sh`がどういう動作をするのかについては`man bash`の起動セクションに書かれています。

> (前略)
>   sh  という名前で bash を起動すると、 bash は古くからある sh の起動動作をできるだけ真似しようとします。 また POSIX 標準にもできるだけ従おうとします。対話的なログインシェルとして起動されると、 あるいは  --login  オプション付きの非対話的シェルとして起動されると、  このシェルはまず  /etc/profile  と  ~/.profile の順でコマンドの読み込みと実行をしようとします。 --noprofile オプションを使うと、この動作を行わないようにできます。 sh という名前の対話的シェルとして起動されると、 bash は環境変数 ENV を調べ、この変数が定義されていればその値を展開し、 展開で得た値をコマンドの読み込みと実行を行うためのファイル名として使います。  sh  という名前で起動されたシェルは、  ほかの起動ファイルからコマンドの読み込みと起動を行うことはないので、 --rcfile オプションは全く効果を持ちません。 sh という名前の非対話的シェルとして起動されると、 このシェルはほかの起動ファイルを何も読み込みません。 sh  として起動された場合、 bash は起動ファイルの読み込みを行った後に POSIX モードに入ります。
>   (後略)

詳細を確認するためにも`man bash`してみることをお勧めします。

Comment: 「man sh」すると「sh」に関するページが表示されず、bashの説明が表示されるのですが。「#!/bin/sh」がどういう動作をするかは「readlink /bin/sh」結果に左右されるのでしょうか？　なぜですか？　そういう仕様だから？　「sh という名前で bash を起動すると」とありますが、sh という名前で sh は起動できない？？

Comment: @re9 ということはCentOSでは/bin/shがbashのシンボリックリンクになっているようです。私が使っているDebian/Ubuntu系ではdashへリンクされています。こういう環境で/bin/shが呼ばれると**shという名前でbashやdashが起動します**。その結果がどうなるかについてはbashに関しては回答内に記したつもりです。

Comment: 「#!/bin/sh」は単に該当ディレクトリ指定しているだけなのですね。ようやく意味が分かりました